# Dropbox usersGetCurrentAccount no member compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, api, dropbox

Using IOS 9.1, running on Xcode 7.1.1. under El Capitan. I am trying out the tutorial on accessing dropbox thru their (new maybe) SwiftDropbox library by following this page.

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/05/try-out-swiftydropbox-the-new-swift-sdk-for-dropbox-api-v2/

Started well, managed to connect and get authorised, but unable to do much more cause the code posted to their tutorial doesn't compile.

```
if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

    // Get the current user's account info
    client.usersGetCurrentAccount().response { response, error in
        if let account = response {
            println("Hello \(account.name.givenName)")
        } else {
            println(error!)
        }
    }

    // List folder
    client.filesListFolder(path: "").response { response, error in
        if let result = response {
            println("Folder contents:")
            for entry in result.entries {
                println(entry.name)
            }
        } else {
            println(error!)
        }
    }
```

Complaining that DropboxClient has no member "usersGetCurrentAccount" or "filesListFolder" which I assume are some sort method calls {pretty new to swift too}. Can not seem to google any useful leads on this? What should this code read/say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bon,

THANKYOU smarx; you put me on the right path. Here is the final code; with two minor fixes to the tutorial he mentioned here.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import SwiftyDropbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func linkButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (Dropbox.authorizedClient == nil) {
            Dropbox.authorizeFromController(self)
        } else {
            print("User is already authorized!")
        }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Verify user is logged into Dropbox
    if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

        // Get the current user's account info
        client.users.getCurrentAccount().response { response, error in
            print("*** Get current account ***")
            if let account = response {
                print("Hello \(account.name.givenName)!")
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }

        // List folder
        client.files.listFolder(path: "").response { response, error in
            print("*** List folder ***")
            if let result = response {
                print("Folder contents:")
                for entry in result.entries {
                    print(entry.name)
                }
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }

        // Upload a file
        let fileData = "Hello!".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        client.files.upload(path: "/hello.txt", body: fileData!).response { response, error in
            if let metadata = response {
                print("*** Upload file ****")
                print("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
                print("Uploaded file revision: \(metadata.rev)")

                // Get file (or folder) metadata
                client.files.getMetadata(path: "/hello.txt").response { response, error in
                    print("*** Get file metadata ***")
                    if let metadata = response {
                        if let file = metadata as? Files.FileMetadata {
                            print("This is a file with path: \(file.pathLower)")
                            print("File size: \(file.size)")
                        } else if let folder = metadata as? Files.FolderMetadata {
                            print("This is a folder with path: \(folder.pathLower)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print(error!)
                    }
                }

                // Download a file

                let destination : (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> NSURL = { temporaryURL, response in
                    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
                    // generate a unique name for this file in case we've seen it before
                    let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
                    let pathComponent = "\(UUID)-\(response.suggestedFilename!)"
                    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
                }
                client.files.download(path: "/hello.txt", destination: destination).response { response, error in
                //client.files.download(path: "/hello.txt").response { response, error in
                    if let (metadata, url) = response {
                        print("*** Download file ***")
                        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                        print("Downloaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
                        print("Downloaded file url: \(url)")
                        print("Downloaded file data: \(data)")
                    } else {
                        print(error!)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're reading a blog post from May about an early preview version of the SDK. Lots of things have changed since that post! Check out https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#tutorial for an up-to-date tutorial.

I believe you want `users.getCurrentAccount` and `files.listFolder`.

Comment: Excellent, almost there; only the last call to download the file in the new tutorial seems to have changed too. I get a "Missing argument for parameter 'destination' call on the compile.